# Is there are truly neat way to do 'if none in collection' test?

Tags: c++, c

so you have a collection and you want to see if NONE of the items in it pass a test. doing the if ANY pass test is easy, and would look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
{
    if(ItemPasses(collection[i]))
    {
        // do code for if any pass
        break;
    }
}
```

but to do the opposite, if NONE pass test, I cant think of a truly neat way to do it, here are the ways I can come up with:

```
// nice to look at but uses an unecessary variable 'anItemPassed'
bool anItemPassed = false;
for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
{
    if(ItemPasses(collection[i]))
    {
        anItemPassed = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!anItemPassed)
{
    //...
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// as efficient as possible but uses gotos.. nobody likes gotos.. lable stuff really isnt that neat.
for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
{
    if (ItemPasses(collection[i]))
    {
        goto ItemPassed;
    }
}
    //...
ItemPassed: { }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// as efficient as possible and doesnt use the rarely used (and usually poorly supported in IDEs) goto/lable stuff, but doesnt use any nice loop construct, does it all manually
int i = 0;
for (; ; )
{
    if (i >= collectionSize)
    {
        //...
        break;
    }

    if (ItemPasses(collection[i]))
    {
        break;
    }

    i++;
}
```

I dont really like any of those, I've always wondered why there was never a construct like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
{
    if (ItemPasses(collection[i]))
    {
        break;
    }
}
finally //executed if the loop terminates normally, not via breaks.
{
    //...
}
```

so in short my question is: Is there are truly neat way to do 'if none in collection' test? if not, is there a reason why the above wouldn't be a good language feature?

EDIT:
I instantly regret putting c++ in the tags. I know there are nice functions to do this, but assuming the boost libraries or whatnot, were also written in c/c++ presumably they encountered the same problem I have. even if these functions are built in to the language, saying 'just call this function' isn't the answer I was looking for in this case.

so maybe I will focus on the last part of my question: Is there a reason why the above wouldn't be a good language feature?
in my view not having it would be like not having the 'else' keyword to go with 'if'

Comment: This depends on the data structure.

Comment: For C++, [there are some nice functions for that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Comment: "None passing" is just the negation of the result of "Any passing"

Comment: What is more efficient about your goto code (#2) then your first block (#1)?

Comment: Javascript has .any and .each.

Comment: @Ben Apart from #1 having an extra 'if check', variable and 2 extra assignments?

Comment: @MattMcNabb that is true but my problem still stands.

Answer (score 5):

For C++ it's pretty trivial (C++11 with none_of, C++14 with the auto lambda)

```
bool noneExist = std::none_of(std::begin(collection), std::end(collection), [](auto &item){
    return item.matchesCondition(); // any evaluation can go here, or you could just supply an existing functor instead of a lambda
});
```

I assign to a bool here, but you could as easily wrap it in an if statement (this assumes an existing function or functor object named MatchCondition, a lambda would work, but that's a lot to read in an if condition):

```
if(std::none_of(std::begin(collection), std::end(collection), MatchCondition)){
    //run your "if none of the above matched" code here.
}
```

And the old C++98 method for completion:

```
if(std::find_if(collection.begin(), collection.end(), MatchCondition) == collection.end()){
    //run your "if none of the above matched" code here.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

"Truly neat" sounds a bit opinion based but here are a few options:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

bool itemPasses(int i) {
  return i > 10;
}

void printIfNonePass1(const std::vector<int>& collection) {
  if (std::none_of(collection.cbegin(), collection.cend(), itemPasses))
    std::cout << "None pass\n";
}

void printIfNonePass2(const std::vector<int>& collection) {
  auto iter = collection.cbegin();
  for(; iter != collection.cend(); ++iter) {
    if (itemPasses(*iter))
      break;
  }
  if (iter == collection.cend())
    std::cout << "None pass\n";
}

void printIfNonePass3(const std::vector<int>& collection) {
  size_t i = 0;
  for(; i != collection.size(); ++i) {
    if (itemPasses(collection[i]))
      break;
  }
  if (i == collection.size())
    std::cout << "None pass\n";
}

bool checkIfNonePass(const std::vector<int>& collection) {
  for(int item : collection) {
    if (itemPasses(item))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

void printIfNonePass4(const std::vector<int>& collection) {
  if (checkIfNonePass(collection))
    std::cout << "None pass\n"; 
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> collection{4,2,10,3};
  printIfNonePass1(collection);
  printIfNonePass2(collection);
  printIfNonePass3(collection);
  printIfNonePass4(collection);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to achieve this by performing the no-match scenario by comparing the iterator against the max.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
{
    if (ItemPasses(collection[i]))
    {
        // do code for if any pass
        break;
    }
}

if (i == collectionSize)
{
    // perform no-match operations
}
```

Comment: You like to test the loop variable _twice_ for every loop iteration?

Comment: umm, that's not what he is doing?  I like this way, its still not ideal as it does an extra if check that is unnecessary in other methods, but at least another variable inst created.

Comment: @matt the answer has been edited since Blastfurnace's comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for c++14, or c++11. Something like this should do what you want.

```
if (find_if(collection.begin(), collection.end(), ItemPasses) == collection.end()) {
    //code if none passes
}
```

edit: Adding c++11 solution as response to comment.

```
if (none_of(collection.begin(), collection.end(), ItemPasses)) {
    //code if none passes
}
```

2:nd edit: Answer the question.

Comment: While true, and good to be aware of, none_of is more concise and C++11 has been out for about 3 years now.

Comment: @M2tM Added c++11 solution.

Comment: The original question was for none_of, you could do !any_of.  Your heart is in the right place but the answer is already posted.

Comment: @M2tM Ah! Sorry. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are interested the internal realization of the algorithm but not applying standard algorithms.

Usually the loop is written the following way

```
CollectionType::size_type i = 0;

while ( i < collectionSize && !ItemPasses(collection[i]) ) ++i;

return ( i == collectionSize );
```

The same can be written with iterators

```
while ( first != last && !ItemPasses( *first ) ) ++first;

return ( first == last );
```

This approach can be applied also in C programs.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, there is no orthgonality in control structures in many languages C included.
The need is obvious, and the language should simplify the work of the programmer, albeit no much will for work and/or change is done in that direction on the side of control structures.

In 1992, I had done a complete proposal and implementation of an orthogonal set of control structures, that could be used in many languages, and the construct you request was included, that is just to confirm the recurrency of the argument and the validity of the need.

The functions of C++ while permit an elegant solution, do not solve the need any way.

An alternative solution to what you already presented is to put the code you need inside the for construct. So the code would become as bellow while the function finalizationCode() should return false.

```
for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize ? true : finalizationCode(); i++)
```

It may be better to put the || construct instead of the if ( ? : ).
So in that case:

```
for(int i=0 ; i < collectionSize || finalizationCode() ;i++)
```

It is anyway guaranted that finalizationCode will be executed only when the condition  `i<collectionSize`
is false.